# Form Date Input Field Format

Tags: jquery, mysql, date

My HTML Form has a

```
<input type="date">
```

Whereas my mysql database's table column is a date, which is stored in the format YYYY-MM-DD, however, the form submits the date field as DD-MM-YYYY, which MYSQL rejects.

Is there any way to get around this or to convert the date values into the correct format, or do i have to use another plugin to accomplish this? (e.g jquery ui)

Comment: What output exactly you want?

Comment: Are you use `PHP` for sending data to mysql?

Comment: yes php to send data through an ajax call

Comment: It will automatically stored in database as YYYY-MM-DD. Go ahead. No need to change the format.

Comment: so if the problem its the date format give a try to [this](http://momentjs.com) it use javascript to change pretty easy the date format and languaje

Comment: @deena, the thing is mysql date columns format is YYYY-MM-DD, but my chrome date input is in DD-MM-YYYY, therefore if the data gets submitted to MYSQL, the query fails as the format is not right.

Comment: Guys no need to change the format.. You just try to insert the value from the date field to database. It will save in the  YYYY-MM-DD format

Comment: @nikz, what about in safari browsers, whereby users enter the date manualy, i dont think that will work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PHP

```
var $date = $your_input_date; //e.g. 03-01-2015
$date = date('Y-m-d', strottime($date));
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: hi there, i dont need the time, just the date, which means i remove H:i:s?

Comment: Yes you can remove `H:i:s`. Check my updated answer

Answer (score 0):

you can use javascript function to change date format

```
function reformatDate(dateStr)
{
  dArr = dateStr.split("-");  // ex input "2010-12-31"
  return dArr[2]+ "-" +dArr[1]+ "-" +dArr[0]; //ex out: "31-12-2010"
}
```

[Check link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2086744/javascript-function-to-convert-date-yyyy-mm-dd-to-dd-mm-yy) for more details

Comment: i see, is there a way whereby i can detect aLL date formats the user uses and convert them to YYYY-MM-DD? but pertaining to this question, your answer is correct.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to insert the date in the database field in the format `Y-m-d H:i:s`. Hence on receiving the date from the form and parse it using the date function something like this:
`date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($date)) //where $date is the date field from the form`

Answer (score 0):

MySQL has a function STR_TO_DATE, so you can convert at once in the query:

```
INSERT INTO atable (datetimefield)
VALUES (STR_TO_DATE('03-01-2015', '%d-%m-%Y'))
```

[Mysql Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date)

Or you can use JQuery UI datepicker which has an option for an alternative field, where you can store the date in the correct format.