# Convert date dd/mm/yyyy to cyymmdd

Tags: javascript, reactjs, date

I have an a date that take from user input in JS(react).

I need to send it in cyymmdd format. how can i convert it ?

like this `01/05/1998 to 980501`

**EDIT**

how can i change it from cyymmdd to dd/mm/yyyy ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can join it by splitting the string by `/` and then reverse the order of the array (of the spitted values) and then join again and cut the first 2 characters:

```js
'01/05/1998'.split('/').reverse().join('').slice(2) // "980501"
```

### Breakdown:

```js
'01/05/1998'
  .split('/') // ["01", "05", "1998"]
  .reverse()  // ["1998", "05", "01"]
  .join('')   // "19980501"
  .slice(2)   //   "980501"
```

Comment: @Allure - can you please elaborate for which scenarios it does not match `cyymmdd`?

Comment: how can i do it backward? from cyymmdd to ddmmyyyy

Comment: @yanirmidler -well, the year `98` can be `1998` or `2098` or `1798`... how would you know for which millennia?

Comment: i want too 1998

Comment: and what do you want to be 20? 1920 or 2020? or 1720?

Comment: @vsync according to cyymmdd format 20 is 1920, 120 is 2020 etc
you wanted a scenario when it does not work: 01/01/2001
your code will return 010101, but is cyymmdd should be 1010101

Answer (score 1):

try this

```js
convertDateFromDDMMYYYYToCYYMMDD('01/05/1998'); //returns desired '980501'

function convertDateFromDDMMYYYYToCYYMMDD(ddmmyyyyDate){
    const testRegex = /^\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}$/
    if(!testRegex.test(ddmmyyyyDate))
        throw new TypeError('date does not match DDMMYYYY format')
    const dateParts = ddmmyyyyDate.split('/')
    const cyy = Number(dateParts.pop()) - 1900
    if(cyy<0)
        throw new Error('date before year 1900')
    return cyy+dateParts[1]+dateParts[0]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use momentjs to do that easy way

```
moment("11/05/1998").format("YYMMDD");
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you want to convert it before you save it in your database, I would suggest using RegEx for changing the format.

Look at this thread, It has the answer you are seeking for.
Here's [a link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2086744/javascript-function-to-convert-date-yyyy-mm-dd-to-dd-mm-yy).

Also, possible duplication.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to do with [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)

```js
const date = "01/05/1998";
const [dd, mm, year] = date.split("/");
const yy = year.match(/\d\d$/)[0];

const result = `${yy}${mm}${dd}`;
console.log(result);
```

Comment: result in your code does not match cyymmdd format, it is yymmdd

Comment: @Allure just see the input of OP and what OP wants in return i.e. output.

Comment: and it matches mentioned format, but your code does not

Comment: @Allure It is matching as expected and as OP wanted `980501`. I don't know what and where are you looking at?